# Multiple $_GET php parameters

Tags: php

If I want to put two to three parameters to the isset $_GET. Do I do it like how it is done in isset $_POST like this?

```
if (isset($_POST['pid'], $_POST['qty']))
```

So it will turn out something like this?

```
if (isset($_GET['pid'], $_GET['qty']))
```

Would this work if I will pass the `$_GET` and the `$_POST` will catch it?

Comment: Yes. It will catch. Make sure you have it in the proper order.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `$_GET` in `isset`

No, it will not automatically check `$_POST`, try

```
if (isset($_GET['pid'], $_GET['qty'], $_POST['pid'], $_POST['qty']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not need `$_POST` if all of your variables are in the `$_GET` array. You can check by doing this -

```
print_r($_GET);
```

Then you could check it with -

```
if (isset($_GET['pid'], $_GET['qty']))...
```